# How to download/open PDF file on Windows using Java/FTP?

Tags: java, pdf, ftp

I am trying to download and open a PDF file from the server using the below code and the org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP client, but it doesn't work on Windows 8. It creates the pdf in a folder but it creates a corrupted file. It works fine on the Mac. Any ideas what I can do in order fix this? Thanks

```
   private static void openFileFTP(String fileName) throws  FileNotFoundException, 
   IOException {

    ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        if (checkConnection()) {

            //Set the type of file to be displayed
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            FileOutputStream outPutFile = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            ftpClient.retrieveFile(serverDirectory + fileName, outPutFile);

            File file = new File(fileName);

            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println(ioe + "error here");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What kind of library do you use for ftp transfer? Perhaps try to close the FileOutputStream.

Comment: I am using the following libraries :org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP; org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP to download a file

- http://www.journaldev.com/974/java-ftp-download-example-using-apache-commons-net-api

Maybe this works for you.